# How can I configure Apple in-app purchases

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I need help implementing in-app purchases. In my app, users can buy individual audios or packs that include these audios. The individual audios always have the same price, while the packs have different prices. Can I create a generic in-app purchase for individual audios (for example "Individual audio: €5") and an in-app purchase for each pack?

It may also be the case that a user wants to buy a pack of which they already have an individual audio, in this case a percentage discount would be applied. How should I manage this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has created an official package for in-app purchases https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

On that package page you will find all the information you need for implementation, as well as the official Google Play and App Store links on how in-app purchases are managed.